# How to fix boolean android.graphics.Bitmap.compress when select image from Photos app?

Tags: java, android, image, bitmap

In my application i want to select an image from **gallery** and **crop** this then convert to **base64**.

In my application i want to select an image from **gallery** and **crop** this then convert to **base64**.
When I select image **from gallery not show me error**, but when **select** image from Photos app show me this this error!

Error :

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main

Process: com.app.test, PID: 19778                                                                         
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null,request=131073, result=0, data=Intent {  launchParam=MultiScreenLaunchParams { mDisplayId=0 mFlags=0 }(has extras) }} to activity {com.app.test/com.app.test.Activity.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.graphics.Bitmap.compress(android.graphics.Bitmap$CompressFormat, int, java.io.OutputStream)' on a null object reference
    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4550)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4593)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap22(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1709)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6724)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1520)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1410)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.graphics.Bitmap.compress(android.graphics.Bitmap$CompressFormat, int, java.io.OutputStream)' on a null object reference
    at com.bidzila.android.Utils.Base64ConverterUtils.convert(Base64ConverterUtils.java:25)
    at com.bidzila.android.Fragments.DashBoardFragment.onActivityResult(DashBoardFragment.java:172)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onActivityResult(FragmentActivity.java:159)
    at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:7256)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4546)
```

**Converter class :**

```
public class Base64ConverterUtils {
    public static Bitmap convert(String base64Str) throws IllegalArgumentException {
        byte[] decodedBytes = Base64.decode(
                base64Str.substring(base64Str.indexOf(",") + 1),
                Base64.DEFAULT
        );

        return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedBytes, 0, decodedBytes.length);
    }

    public static String convert(Bitmap bitmap) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, outputStream);

        return Base64.encodeToString(outputStream.toByteArray(), Base64.DEFAULT);
    }
}
```

**My fragment class :**

```
public class DashBoardFragment extends BaseFragment {

    /*    @BindView(R.id.addPhoto)
        ImageView addPhoto;*/
    private Handler handler;
    private Context context;
    private View v;
    private PrefsUtils prefsUtils;
    private ImageView addPhoto;
    private LinearLayout noLoginFrag_btn;
    private TextView textView2, dash_winnerTxt, dash_allBidsTxt, dash_allBidsTxt2, dash_winnerTxt2, dash_notWinTxt, dash_bougthTxt;
    private ProgressBar profileProgress;
    private File file;
    private Uri uri;
    private Intent CamIntent, GalIntent, CropIntent;
    public static final int RequestPermissionCode = 1;
    private DisplayMetrics displayMetrics;
    private int width, height;
    private String base64String, base64StringForSite;
    private APIs apIs;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        handler = new Handler();
        context = getActivity();
        prefsUtils = new PrefsUtils(context);
        if (prefsUtils.isExist(PrefsKeys.PHONE_NUMBER.name())) {
            v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dashboard, null);
            addPhoto = v.findViewById(R.id.addPhoto);
            textView2 = v.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
            dash_winnerTxt = v.findViewById(R.id.dash_winnerTxt);
            dash_allBidsTxt = v.findViewById(R.id.dash_allBidsTxt);
            dash_allBidsTxt2 = v.findViewById(R.id.dash_allBidsTxt2);
            dash_winnerTxt2 = v.findViewById(R.id.dash_winnerTxt2);
            dash_notWinTxt = v.findViewById(R.id.dash_notWinTxt);
            dash_bougthTxt = v.findViewById(R.id.dash_bougthTxt);
            profileProgress = v.findViewById(R.id.profileProgress);
            apIs = ApiClient.getClient().create(APIs.class);

            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        textView2.setText(Constants.profileResponse.getRes().getUser().getName());
                        dash_winnerTxt.setText(Constants.profileResponse.getRes().getWinner() + "");
                        dash_winnerTxt2.setText(Constants.profileResponse.getRes().getWinner() + "");
                        dash_allBidsTxt.setText(Constants.profileResponse.getRes().getRegistered() + "");
                        dash_allBidsTxt2.setText(Constants.profileResponse.getRes().getRegistered() + "");
                        dash_bougthTxt.setText(Constants.profileResponse.getRes().getBought() + "");
                        dash_notWinTxt.setText(Constants.profileResponse.getRes().getRegistered() - Constants.profileResponse.getRes().getWinner() + "");

                        Glide.with(context)
                                .load(Constants.SERVERImg + Constants.profileResponse.getRes().getUser().getAvatarFile())
                                .asBitmap()
                                .centerCrop()
                                //.diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE)
                                //.skipMemoryCache(true)
                                .signature(new StringSignature(String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis())))
                                .into(new BitmapImageViewTarget(addPhoto) {
                                    @Override
                                    protected void setResource(Bitmap resource) {
                                        RoundedBitmapDrawable circularBitmapDrawable =
                                                RoundedBitmapDrawableFactory.create(context.getResources(), resource);
                                        circularBitmapDrawable.setCircular(true);
                                        addPhoto.setImageDrawable(circularBitmapDrawable);
                                    }
                                });

                        addPhoto.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View view) {
                                getImageFromGallery();
                            }
                        });
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                    }
                }
            }, 1000);

        } else {
            v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_no_login_dash, null);
            noLoginFrag_btn = v.findViewById(R.id.noLoginFrag_btn);
            noLoginFrag_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    startActivity(new Intent(context, RegisterPhoneActivity.class));
                    getActivity().finish();
                }
            });
        }

        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(final int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == 0 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            imageCropFunction();
        } else if (requestCode == 2) {
            if (data != null) {
                uri = data.getData();
                imageCropFunction();
            }
        } else if (requestCode == 1) {

            if (data != null) {
                Bundle bundle = data.getExtras();
                Bitmap bitmap = bundle.getParcelable("data");
                base64String = Base64ConverterUtils.convert(bitmap);

                Bitmap bitmap1 = Base64ConverterUtils.convert(base64String);
                addPhoto.setImageBitmap(bitmap1);

                profileProgress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                addPhoto.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                Call<ProfileResponse> call = apIs.getUploadBase64Avatar(sendBase64Image(prefsUtils.getFromShared(PrefsKeys.PHONE_NUMBER.name()), base64String, "jpg"));
                call.enqueue(new Callback<ProfileResponse>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call<ProfileResponse> call, Response<ProfileResponse> response) {
                        if (response.body().getStatus().equals("ok")) {
                            profileProgress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            addPhoto.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            Glide.with(context)
                                    .load(Constants.SERVERImg + Constants.profileResponse.getRes().getUser().getAvatarFile())
                                    .asBitmap()
                                    .centerCrop()
                                    //.diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE)
                                    //.skipMemoryCache(true)
                                    .signature(new StringSignature(String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis())))
                                    .into(new BitmapImageViewTarget(addPhoto) {
                                        @Override
                                        protected void setResource(Bitmap resource) {
                                            RoundedBitmapDrawable circularBitmapDrawable =
                                                    RoundedBitmapDrawableFactory.create(context.getResources(), resource);
                                            circularBitmapDrawable.setCircular(true);
                                            addPhoto.setImageDrawable(circularBitmapDrawable);
                                        }
                                    });
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call<ProfileResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                        profileProgress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }

    private void imageCropFunction() {

        try {
            CropIntent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");

            CropIntent.setDataAndType(uri, "image/*");

            CropIntent.putExtra("crop", "true");
            CropIntent.putExtra("outputX", 200);
            CropIntent.putExtra("outputY", 200);
            CropIntent.putExtra("aspectX", 3);
            CropIntent.putExtra("aspectY", 3);
            CropIntent.putExtra("scaleUpIfNeeded", true);
            CropIntent.putExtra("return-data", true);

            startActivityForResult(CropIntent, 1);

        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {

        }
    }


    private void getImageFromGallery() {
        GalIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);

        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(GalIntent, "Select image"), 2);

    }
```

How can i fix it?

Comment: Android does not have a `CROP` `Intent`. There are many [image-cropping libraries available for Android](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/45). Please use one. Also, do not ignore exceptions (like you are with `ActivityNotFoundException`).

Comment: @CommonsWare, can you send to me code with my above codes? please

Answer (score 0):

NullPointerException tells you, that you are trying to do something with object, that appears to be null.
You would have to debug why the bitmap passed to function (not base64 representation) is null, maybe you put it wrongly into arguments Bundle.

It is hard to give proper answer since I can't see which lines the exception marks, so you have to do a bit on your own :)

Comment: can you send to me code with my above codes? please

Comment: The bitmap in bitmap.compress() line in Base64ConverterUtils is null, so you have to check why it is null

Answer (score 0):

Error is caused because **bitmap is null.**

Declare **Bitmap bitmap;** as a global variable.

And use the **bitmap** object in your **onActivityResult** method.